# No insertion to a MySQL database of scraped data using scrapy

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I use Scrapy to get data and I want to store them inside a MySQL database. To perform that, I copy and adapt a large part of the code [here](https://github.com/rolando/dirbot-mysql).

It looks really nice, but there is no way to make it work on my side. The code doesn't make any errors, data are properly scraped but my database is empty.
Here is the code of my pipeline :

```
class MySQLPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dbpool = dbpool

    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        dbargs = dict(
            host=settings['MYSQL_HOST'],
            db=settings['MYSQL_DBNAME'],
            user=settings['MYSQL_USER'],
            passwd=settings['MYSQL_PASSWD'],
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True,
        )
        dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', **dbargs)
        return cls(dbpool)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        d = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._do_upsert, item, spider)
        d.addErrback(self._handle_error, item, spider)
        d.addBoth(lambda _: item)
        return d

    def _do_upsert(self, conn, item, spider):
        guid = self._get_guid(item)
        now = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')

        conn.execute("""SELECT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM produits WHERE guid = %s
        )""", (guid, ))
        ret = conn.fetchone()

        if ret:
            conn.execute("""
                UPDATE produits
                SET product=%s, link=%s, price=%s, description=%s, image_urls=%s, image=%s, brand=%s, couleur=%s, gamme=%s, largeur=%s, profondeur=%s, hauteur=%s, longueur=%s, diametre=%s, updated=%s
                WHERE guid=%s
        """, (item['product'], item['link'], item['price'], item['description'], item['image_urls'], item['image'], item['brand'], item['couleur'], item['gamme'], item['largeur'], item['profondeur'], item['hauteur'], item['longueur'], item['diametre'], now, guid))
            spider.log("Item updated in db: %s %r" % (guid, item))
            self.dbpool.commit()
        else:
            conn.execute("""
                INSERT INTO produits (product, link, price, description, image_urls, image, brand, couleur, gamme, largeur, prodonfeur, hauteur, longueur, diametre, updated, guid)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )
        """, (item['product'], item['link'], item['price'], item['description'], item['image_urls'], item['image'], item['brand'], item['couleur'], item['gamme'], item['largeur'], item['profondeur'], item['hauteur'], item['longueur'], item['diametre'], now, guid))
            spider.log("Item stored in db: %s %r" % (guid, item))
            self.dbpool.commit()


    def _handle_error(self, failure, item, spider):
        log.err(failure)

    def _get_guid(self, item):
        return md5(item['link']).hexdigest()
```

Here is the code of my settings :

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'Comparito.pipelines.ImagesPipeline':1,
'Comparito.pipelines.MySQLPipeline':300,
}
```

If someone can help me to understand why it doesn't insert anything in my database, it would be great.

Thank you

Comment: before performing sql code, put it in a string and print the string.  See if it is doing what you want.  This will also show which part executed.  If that looks good, write some simple sql and executed it with your code to see your db is setup correctly

Comment: Thank you Joel, good idea. No, it seems it doesn't insert string neither. It would mean the problem is directly linked to the connection to the database, which might be wrong. If you have any clue on the way to connect properly the database to my python scripts, please let me know !